# How to navigate in Angular 4 with filter url subscribe

Tags: angular, url, router, subscribe

I want to change url in browser without notify activatedRoute about this changes, so as to run code in subscribe of url, when component is initializing or user click in browser Undo/Redo

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.form = this.initForm(); 
  this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(params => 
  { 
     //run only when component is loading or user click undo/redo in browser
     this.form = this.initForm(); 
  }); 
} 

public submit(): void { 
  let url = this.urlBuilder.build(this.form);
  //change url in browser and add to history, without notify activatedRoute about changes
  this.router.navigateByUrl(url); 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you factor out that callback so you can also call it directly, instead?